# Spring JUnit + Mockito + In memory Database (H2)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, h2

I'm currently using Mockito and In memory Database (H2) in order to test some services and dao.

I've tried to test a method (createRoad) of my service that contains some call of dao method :

```
@Service(value = "RoadsService")
public class RoadsService implements IRoadsService {

@Autowired
private IRoadsDao roadsDao;

...

@Override
public long createRoad(CreateRoadCriteria criteria) {
    String roaCodeToCopy = "";
    RoadsCriteria roadsCriteria = new RoadsCriteria();
    roadsCriteria.setCe(criteria.getCe());
    roadsCriteria.setDeliveryDate(new Date());
    List<WebRoadsModel> listRoadsCe = roadsDao
            .getRoadsByCEAndDeliveryDate(roadsCriteria);
    for (WebRoadsModel wrm : listRoadsCe) {
        if (wrm.getRoaCode().endsWith("90")) {
            roaCodeToCopy = wrm.getRoaCode();
            break;
        }
    }
    criteria.setRoadCode(StringUtils.substring(roaCodeToCopy, 0, 4)
            + criteria.getRoadCode());
    // 2. Creation of the new road
    long idNewRoad = roadsDao.createNewRoad(criteria);

    if (!"".equals(roaCodeToCopy) && listRoadsCe.get(0) != null) {
        roaCodeToCopy = listRoadsCe.get(0).getRoaCode();
        // 3. Copy dates closed of this trn
        RoadsCriteria newRoadCreated = new RoadsCriteria();
        newRoadCreated.setCe(criteria.getCe());
        newRoadCreated.setRoadId(idNewRoad);
        // 4. Paste it for the new road
        deliveryCalendarDao.copyClosedDates(roadsDao
                .getRoadByCriteria(newRoadCreated).get(0).getRoaCode(),
                roaCodeToCopy);
    }

    return idNewRoad;
    }

...
}
```

I need to mock the method called **getRoadsByCEAndDeliveryDate**, because the sql query behind that is not managed by the H2 driver (query with "RANK"). Then, I want to use H2 with the other method in this service.

I've tried this :

```
public class RoadsServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private RoadsService roadsService;

@Mock
private MockRoadDao roadsDao;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {

}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void createRoad(){
    CreateRoadCriteria criteria = new CreateRoadCriteria();
    criteria.setRoadCode("AA");
    criteria.setRoadName("ANAME");
    criteria.setCe("2");
    criteria.setDriver(1);
    criteria.setVehicle(1);
    criteria.setSupplier(1);

    List<WebRoadsModel> expected = new ArrayList<WebRoadsModel>();
    Mockito.when(roadsDao.getRoadsByCEAndDeliveryDate((RoadsCriteria) Mockito.any())).thenReturn(expected);
    Mockito.when(roadsDao.getNextVal(Mockito.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
    Mockito.when(roadsDao.createNewRoad(criteria)).thenCallRealMethod();

    long result = roadsService.createRoad(criteria);
    Assert.assertEquals(5, result);
}
}
```

It is almost good except the assertEquals.
According to my sql file used with my in memory database, i have a sql sequence like this :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SEQ_SITI_ROADS"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 5 CACHE 20 ;
```

When I run my test, the result is 0.
It seems that the MockRoadDao is not initialized.

```
public class MockRoadDao extends RoadsDao {

public MockRoadDao() throws DatabaseUnitException, SQLException, MalformedURLException {
    IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("./src/test/resources/dataset.xml"));

    DataSource dataSource = TestUtils.dataSource();

    IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource);
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, dataSet);

    User user = new User();
    user.setLangCountry("ENFR");
    BackendContextHolder.setBackendIdentifier(new BackendIdentifierImpl(user));
    final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
}

}

public class TestUtils {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestUtils.class);

public static DataSource datasource;

/**
 * @return
 */
public static DataSource dataSource() {
    if (datasource == null) {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("classpath:/siti-create.sql").build();
        datasource = db;
    }
    return datasource;
}
...
}
```

Could you please help me :)

Thank you in advance

**Edit :**
@Baski : When I remove @Mock and use ReflectionUtils instead, the constructor of MockRoadDAO is called. But, when I run the test, the method **roadsDao.getRoadsByCEAndDeliveryDate()** is not mocked with Mockito, the method is really called and unfortunately the SQL query is not managed by the H2 driver.

```
public class RoadsServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private RoadsService roadsService;

private MockRoadDao roadsDao;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {

}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    roadsDao = new MockRoadDao();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(roadsService, "roadsDao", roadsDao);
}

@Test
public void createRoad(){
    CreateRoadCriteria criteria = new CreateRoadCriteria();
    criteria.setRoadCode("AA");
    criteria.setRoadName("ANAME");
    criteria.setCe("2");
    criteria.setDriver(1);
    criteria.setVehicle(1);
    criteria.setSupplier(1);

    List<WebRoadsModel> expected = new ArrayList<WebRoadsModel>();
    Mockito.when(roadsDao.getRoadsByCEAndDeliveryDate((RoadsCriteria) Mockito.any())).thenReturn(expected);
    Mockito.when(roadsDao.getNextVal(Mockito.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
    Mockito.when(roadsDao.createNewRoad(criteria)).thenCallRealMethod();

    long result = roadsService.createRoad(criteria);
    Assert.assertEquals(5, result);
}
}
```

Comment: why @ Mock on DAO when you are in fact using emulator (inmemory db)? Remove @ Mock on DAO & call the constructor in the setup method.

Comment: I have to mock a method (roadsDao.getRoadsByCEAndDeliveryDate) and not the others, because with my in memory database it does not work (the sql query contains "RANK" and the H2 in memory database don't understand that...).

Comment: I see you are trying to do partial mock on the stub. As I said earlier having @ mock on your stub DAO will not really call the stub you created. (a) Remove @ mock on MockRoadDAO and (b) In setUp method construct the MockRoadDAO and use ReflectionUtil to set the roadsDao inside the service class. Use sysout or other mechanism to confirm the constructor of MockRoadDAO is getting invoked.

Comment: @Baski Thank you for your help :) i've edited my post to explain my problem with that.

Comment: you need to wrap the instance of MockRoadDao with "mock" or "spy".